# logical partitions overlap

Tags: partition, fdisk, cfdisk

I have two hard disks. An 80GB and 1TB. Everything works fine. I am running Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Today I ran `sudo /sbin/cfdisk` and saw this:

[image]

Then I decided to run: **sudo /sbin/fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004b4d8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   118685420    59341686+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       118685694   156301311    18807809    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       149876736   156301311     3212288   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       118685696   149876735    15595520   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000203b8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   524290047   262144000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2      1083736062  1953523711   434893825    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb3       524290048  1048578047   262144000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb4      1048578048  1083734297    17578125   83  Linux
/dev/sdb5      1937403904  1953523711     8059904   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6   *  1083736064  1511554840   213909388+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb7      1924462592  1937391615     6464512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb8      1511555072  1924458495   206451712   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

And **blkid** shows me this:

```
aruna@debian:~$ /sbin/blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="6672b95a-0a8a-4cd6-a146-2223aaa02a16" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="8c482432-b70a-49f5-9547-876b3b20bebb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="5a201b78-7231-4f93-baa7-f596d0666486" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04.4 L" UUID="092d3383-368f-4945-b0c7-b1a3d3ed64df" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="kernel-stuff" UUID="15684a31-dbbf-4411-8fe9-593d79d3a86f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="back-up" UUID="b416f822-d40a-44ba-a4ca-82a3c65705e0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="f76544b6-a687-4d7b-a79d-844a3d0b0e1c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="3c8fce17-5948-43e7-9662-921e65c7faa7" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sdb7: UUID="e6df7849-fda4-44a5-9a8f-ec4ca5130aba" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb8: UUID="200f9328-ae6b-4fe9-9d94-24ffd391bbe9" TYPE="ext4"
```

And **lsblk** shows me this:

```
aruna@debian:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  74.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  56.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.1G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  14.9G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   250G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   250G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0  16.8G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   7.7G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0   204G  0 part /media/3c8fce17-5948-43e7-9662-921e65c7faa7
├─sdb7   8:23   0   6.2G  0 part 
└─sdb8   8:24   0 196.9G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

What would be the best way to resolve this overlapped partition issue ?

Comment: I don't see any overlaps, but this is very hard to see, because the partitions should be ordered. It is also required for compliance with specs.

Comment: Hi Martin
 
    /dev/sda2       118685694   **156301311**    18807809    5  Extended 
    /dev/sda5       149876736   **156301311**     3212288   82  Linux swap / Solaris

I have bold faced the end, is that not a overlap ?

Comment: But this is not an overlap, because it is an extended partition containing logical partitions within. This is intended and ok.

Comment: Oh.. alright understood and thanks. So why is cfdisk complaining about overlapped partitons ?

Comment: I cannot tell exactly, but it could be that cfdisk is confused with unordered partitions. But the last time this condition was a problem for me was with Windows 95 (Windows wrote outside the partition boundaries). Not sure if today's tools/systems still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problems. Partitions sda2 and sdb2 are extended partition boot records and include up to four partitions inside. There's MS-DOS partitioning type, you can read about it at  [Extended boot record](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record)